# Favicon.ico doesn't display on web site

Tags: html

I have added this line of code `<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="ftp://www.dtestrdtestrl.com/dtestrdtestrl/favicon.ico">` but when I visit the website http://www.dtestrdtestrl.com/ it shows the default internet icon. I have converted the icon and put it in the website directory

Comment: Why are you using `ftp://` for your icon?  You probably need `http://` (or `https://`).

Comment: Use your browsers development console to check the network request. It will tell you what is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="ftp://www.dtestrdtestrl.com/dtestrdtestrl/favicon.ico">
```

to

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```

There isn't public access to this FTP location

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `rel="icon"` now. I think `rel="shortcut icon"` was used for Internet Explorer as per as [HTML Favicon Proper Usage](https://solidlystated.com/design/html-favicon-proper-usage/):

> Shortcut is simply a workaround for Internet Explorer to designate an
> icon that is not named `favicon.ico`.

And since Internet Explorer is deprecated, so your code will be:

```html
<link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/favicon.ico">
```